# Chrome DevTools Workspaces Keyboard Shortcuts (Tabbing?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

### 1) Is it possible to tab through open files?

```
Example:

CMD+1  -- switches to tab 1
```

---

### 2) Is it possible to fold code?

```
Examples:


CMD+K1 -- folds code at first layer of indentation

CMD+KJ -- unfolds all code
```

---

(Hoping this reaches far corners of the intergalactic web)

Comment: seems like nobody has anything to say so they mark it down

Answer (score 2):

**1)** The only thing I know how to go on file is with the following:

If you are in `Sources` tab in DevTools, go on any file so the source code appear and then press `Ctrl + G` and new window with search bar will pop up where you can write the name of the file you want to go to (you may need to remove the `:` when the window pop up).


**2)** The answer is No, but you can check this thread: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=328431
on a regular basic to find out will or/and when this will be implemented.